# Does it make sense to start a transaction for one SaveChanges call?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Does it make sense to Begin transaction, if I want to call `SaveChanges()` only once?

for example:

```
    using (var foo = ContextFactory.CreateFooContext())
    {
        using (var transaction = foo.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                Bar bar = new Bar()
                { 


                };

                bar = foo.Bars.Add(bar);
                foo.SaveChanges();

                transaction.Commit();
                return bar.Id;
            }
            catch
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

I couldn't find if there are any advantages of starting new transaction, if I call SaveChanges only once. I mean... there is no chance of saving partial data, right?

Comment: No, SaveChanges is already wrapped in a transaction so adding an additional one on top of that is useless.

Comment: There's one obvious and common flaw in your code: you shouldn't call `transaction.Rollback` in a `catch`; the `using` will take care of that already if the transaction has not been committed, resulting in a confusing error message about being unable to rollback since the transaction has already been aborted. The `try` .. `catch` can be eliminated entirely in this case. (This is separate from how you should use transactions with EF, which I know less about since I don't use EF.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks! I really appreciate your comment. Igor, thank you as well